# Using sniffing in Scapy

Tags: scapy, sniffing

I am using Scapy to monitor towards man in the middle I would like to know in Scapy what does mean the following terms???

```
%IP.src%
%TCP.sport% 
%IP.dst%
%TCP.dport%  
%TCP.flags%
%TCP.payload%
```

Comment: I'm not Scapy user but seems pretty straight forward: 1- Source IP Address, 2- TCP Source Port, 3- Destination IP Address, 4- TCP Destination Port, 5- TCP Flags, 6- TCP Payload (message body)

Comment: Thank you very much. It was clear your answer :)

Comment: Cool, glad to help. Im then adding it as actual answer.

Comment: %TCP.flags% will give you the flags number and not the flag in string format. For that you have to sprintf().

Answer (score 1):

I'm not Scapy user but seems pretty straight forward:

- Source IP Address
- TCP Source Port
- Destination IP Address
- TCP Destination Port
- TCP Flags
- TCP Payload (message body)

Answer (score 0):

These are the useable TCP-Flags.

```
# TCP-Flags
FIN = 0x01
SYN = 0x02
RST = 0x04
PSH = 0x08
ACK = 0x10
URG = 0x20
ECE = 0x40
CWR = 0x80
```

You coul'd test for a flag with the & operator

e.g.:

```
if paket[TCP].flags & SYN:
    do_anything()
```